# How to run the web application project on Tomcat server in eclipse on my local machine

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am using eclipse, where i created the web application project as my project is to be deployed on app engine. So when i try to run the project, there is no 'run on server' option to run the project on Tomcat. Please help me, am stuck on this for almost 3 hours and didn't find any posts in google either to address this problem,

Comment: How did you set up the server inside of eclipse? Which version of Eclipse do you use, which steps did you take **exactly** to set up the project?

Comment: i am using eclipse luna 4.4 version with tomcat 7 server.... as @sachin commented, i need to create a dynamic project to run on tomcat server other wise copy the 'war' directory to the 'webapps' folder of tomcat installation directory and run it, so basically only the 'dynamic projects' can run on tomcat server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a web application from eclipse you need to create "Dynamic web Project". and make sure you are using J2EE perspective.